# Complex Query with Sphinx

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I am using [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/). It's working fine for me except one problem: I need to exclude some entries where a specific field doesn't contain a word.

Something that would look like this in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table
   WHERE yescolumn = 'query' 
   AND othercolumn not like '%keyword%'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Sphinx's extended query syntax to pick the fields you want to search.  Try running a query through Sphinx like this:

```
@yescolumn query @othercolumn -keyword
```

So in a PHP page you might have a link to a Sphinx database named `$sphinx`:

```
$sphinx->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
$results = $sphinx->Query('@yescolumn query @othercolumn -keyword');
```

More information here: http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#searching